# How to stop Bootstrap 4's grid from breaking column content in two when resizing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First of all let me say this is my first time trying to use Bootstrap's grid system, so I apologize in advance if it's a stupid question.

I'm trying to build a responsive 3 column page, each one with an image and a spotify player.

I've got it working when viewed on a full window:
[3 columns display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfEXb.png)

and also in a small window:
[1 column display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiMnu.png)

but when it resizes to 2 columns, the contents of the 3rd column get broken in two:
[2 columns display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9ZfL.png)

My current code is:

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center">
            <img src="images/capa_marrow.jpg" height="300" width="300">
            <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/20zacwBmt9ay2EcAYb8CLc" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center">
            <img src="images/capa_difraction.jpg" height="300" width="300">
            <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/4sbQLJP8qPaiQXNqTYAYSp" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center">
            <img src="images/capa_chromatic.jpg" height="300" width="300">
            <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/4X9FVjDibj5yWgZYVwOVRj" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How can I stop this from happening, so that the image is always displayed above the spotify player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could fix this. I'd use flexbox. Add `d-flex flex-column` to each of your `col` divs.

This is happening because both `iframe` and `img` are `display: inline` by default - meaning they'll be side by side if there's enough room. Your 3 column and 1 column displays don't have enough room to stack the `img` over the `iframe`, but in the 2 column display, your 3rd column has enough room to display them side by side.

You'll see this even better if you change your `container` to `container-fluid` and make your screen REALLY wide (like make it get wider than your computer screen).